# C++ Generic Programming on Multimap

Tags: c++, stl, generic-programming

The multimap is like below:

```
int main() {
    multimap<int, string> coll;
    coll = { {5, "tagged"} ,
             {2, "a"} ,
             {1, "this"} ,
             {4, "of"} ,
             {6, "strings"} ,
             {1, "is"} ,
             {3, "multimap"} 
          };
}
```

Now, I'd like to get a function template like below to print all value elements in such containers one by one, including `multimap` but not limited to this type of map and this particular pair of template parameters.

```
void PrintAllMaps(multimap<int, string> map) {
    for (auto elem : map) {
        cout << elem.second << ' ';
    }
    cout << endl;
}
```

Comment: Does a template function not work?

Answer (score 6, accepted):

> including multimap but not limited

If I understand correctly, you want a template template function:

```
template <
    typename T1, 
    typename T2, 
    typename T3, 
    typename T4, 
    template <typename, typename, typename, typename> class M>
void PrintAllMaps(M<T1, T2, T3, T4>& map) {
    ...
}
```

Note that `std::multimap` and other `std::map` like containers take actually more than 2 template parameters, the rest of them having default types.

See the [<kbd>Live Demo</kbd>](http://coliru.stacked-crooked.com/a/f5d30101b9ba083a)

Comment: Good answer, covering the general case.

Comment: Thanks for help! Another questions: what containers do this template affects? So far, i have known like multimap, unordered_multimap, map, unordered_map, any more? And such the template does have 4 parameters, doesn't it? thanks again.

Comment: @HuangCheng This will work for all class templates (e.g. containers) that have 4 template arguments. Just keep in mind that template arguments can have default values, so the number of template arguments a class template has is not always obvious.

Answer (score 5):

I've had good luck with generic container functions:

```
template <class Map>
void PrintMapToStream(std::ostream &stream, const Map &map) {
    for (auto &elem : map)
        stream << elem.second << ' ';
    stream << std::endl;
}
```

Of course, this will fail with confusing error messages if you call it on something that doesn't allow you to iterate over pairs.

Answer (score 0):

```
template <class TKey>
template <class TValue>
void PrintMapToStream(std::ostream &stream, multimap<TKey, TValue> map)
{
    for (auto elem : map)
        stream << elem.second << ' ';

    stream << std::endl;
}
```

Then just:

```
PrintMapToStream(std::cout, map);
```

Comment: The OP is looking for something that is not limited to just a multimap.